# How to export HTML table in R and have control over line borders?

Tags: r

Are there any functions in R that permit the exporting of HTML tables as part of an R Markdown or related weaved document and that permit detailed control over table line borders?

E.g., Imagine a matrix like this:

```
x <- matrix(c("", "M", "F", "Good", 
"23", "17", "Bad", "23", "4"), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

what command would output a proper HTML table with features like this:

```
       --------
       M     F
---------------
 Good  23    17
---------------
 Bad   23    4
---------------
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to know what the HTML/CSS would be for a table like that, or do you just need to know what tool in R would let you build it?

Comment: As far I know, there is currently no driver for Markdown as these exist for latex and html in (xtable, Hmisc, tables). This is one of the reasons I do not understand the Markdown hype in the knitr world, even if knitr certainly is a breakthrough in documentation.

Comment: Try xtable or r2html. Once you have the HTML markup, you can do everything with the borders in CSS.

Comment: Given that you can include HTML in Markdown, I'm interested in R functions that generate the necessary HTML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try my really young package under heavy development named to [pander](https://github.com/daroczig/pander) which tries to print R objects in [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) markdown format.

Lazy example:

```
> x <- matrix(c("", "M", "F", "Good", "23", "17", "Bad", "23", "4"), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
> pandoc(x)

+------+------+------+
|      | M    | F    |
+------+------+------+
| Good | 23   | 17   |
+------+------+------+
| Bad  | 23   | 4    |
+------+------+------+
```

I am just working on some functions resulting in other table syntax like "simple table" or "multiline table" (see Pandoc's readme).

---

P. S.:
you could also export this table easily to HTML (besides other formats like docx, odt etc.) with the (not yet documented) `Pandoc` reference class like:

```
> myReport <- Pandoc$new()
> myReport$add(x)
> myReport

Anonymous's report
==================
 written by *Anonymous* at *Sun May 27 21:04:22 2012*

  This report holds 1 block(s). 

---

+------+------+------+
|      | M    | F    |
+------+------+------+
| Good | 23   | 17   |
+------+------+------+
| Bad  | 23   | 4    |
+------+------+------+


---

Proc. time:  0.009 seconds. 

> myReport$format <- 'html'
> myReport$export()

Exported to */tmp/pander-4e9c12ff63a6.[md|html]* under 0.031 seconds.
```

---

P.S. second: you could also [`brew`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html) (like sweave) a text document with `Pandoc.brew` which would auto-transform your `<%=...%>` tags from internal R object to Pandoc markdown format. Short example (of course this would work with file input too, now I just `brew` an R character vector):

```
> t <- '# Title
+ 
+ A nice matrix:
+ 
+ <%=matrix(c("", "M", "F", "Good", "23", "17", "Bad", "23", "4"), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)%>
+ 
+ Bye-bye!'
> 
> Pandoc.brew(text=t)
# Title

A nice matrix:

+------+------+------+
|      | M    | F    |
+------+------+------+
| Good | 23   | 17   |
+------+------+------+
| Bad  | 23   | 4    |
+------+------+------+

Bye-bye!
```