# How to get R to output body scripts to format HTML tables using a similar approach as gvisTable?

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to work out how to generate formatted HTML tables in a way that does not require use of styles that are placed in the HTML header. [I've broadly asked about this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842886/how-to-produce-html-tables-and-accompanying-css-using-r-markdown-or-html-sweave), but received one answer that mentioned using the header and another answer that involves using pandoc (**Update: see bottom of this post regarding new answer posted since asking this question**.
I'd like to have an R function that writes all the HTML formatting required for a formatted HTML table in one place.

I've recently been playing around with `gvisTable` and it is capable of writing all relevant information in one place:

The following code

````
```{r results='asis'}
simpleData <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow=3))
tab2 <- gvisTable(simpleData, 
                   options=list(width = 600, height = 300))
print(tab2, "chart")
```
````

will output the following into an R Markdown document:

```
<!-- jsHeader -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// jsData 
function gvisDataTableID273f3d05cccd ()
{
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var datajson =
[
 [
 1,
4,
7 
],
[
 2,
5,
8 
],
[
 3,
6,
9 
] 
];
data.addColumn('number','X1');
data.addColumn('number','X2');
data.addColumn('number','X3');
data.addRows(datajson);
return(data);
}

// jsDrawChart
function drawChartTableID273f3d05cccd() {
  var data = gvisDataTableID273f3d05cccd();
  var options = {};
options["allowHtml"] = true;
options["width"] =    600;
options["height"] =    300;

     var chart = new google.visualization.Table(
       document.getElementById('TableID273f3d05cccd')
     );
     chart.draw(data,options);


}


// jsDisplayChart 
function displayChartTableID273f3d05cccd()
{
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:["table"] }); 
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartTableID273f3d05cccd);
}

// jsChart 
displayChartTableID273f3d05cccd()

<!-- jsFooter -->  
//-->
</script>

<!-- divChart -->

<div id="TableID273f3d05cccd"
  style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">
</div>
```

And when this is placed in context, a gvisTable is produced. See [the second table in this output](http://rpubs.com/jeromyanglim/simple_gvisTable_example).

Thus, a simple R function has outputted all the necessary HTML for the creation of a fairly sophisticated table. Ultimately I'd like to have the same degree of table formatting control seen in LateX, only for R Markdown. And it would be good that given such posts often appear on blogs, through syndication, in RSS readers, and so on that the formatting commands were in the body.

#### Questions

- Is it possible to use an approach similar to gvis (e.g., scripts in the HTML body) to format HTML tables (e.g., lines, cell formatting, cell height and width, fonts, etc.)?
- Are there any existing R functions that support the production of such tables?
- Do the assumptions of this question make sense, or is there some other way to achieve my broader aims of precise HTML table formatting with R Markdown?

#### Update

[Joe has added an answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893563/180892) where he mentions three options (style in body; javascript which embeds style in header; and scoped style blocks). So I guess the main question that remains is whether there are any interfaces exist to faciliate using such approaches with R Markdown code blocks.

Comment: You also received an answer saying you can just put the CSS in a style block right next to the table. I was in the middle of writing exactly that answer when I spotted it had already been answered there. What's wrong with that solution to your Q1?

Comment: Sorry; that answer was added after I asked this question. I've updated my question to focus more on R implementation.

Comment: markdown should just pass HTML through. So just stick a style block in before the markdown that generates the table (see package:xtable for that)

Answer (score 3):

From the [RStudio Docs](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering), you can set `knitr` to use a custom stylesheet using:

```
# Set Custom CSS
options(rstudio.markdownToHTML=
  function(inputFile, outputFile) {      
    require(markdown)
    markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, stylesheet='custom.css')   
  }
)
```

Just replace `stylesheet='custom.css'` with the file path to your stylesheet.

Then, you can combine `xtable` and `print`with the option `type="html"` in a chunk and you'll get a well-formatted table.

`xtable` also produces LaTeX if that's desirable.